# Moment js "isSameOrAfter()" is false when comparing current time to event less then 1 day away

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I want to check if the current utc time is less then 1 day from an event date. And the event date I pass in I subtract one day. Essentially I'm looking to see if the current utc time is less then a day away from an event date, but this query is coming back false, instead of true!!

ex. passing in a utc time and sub 1 day, then check if it's less then one day away from current utc time

```
if (moment().utc().isSameOrAfter(moment("4/13/2018 7:30:00 PM").add(-1, 'days').utc())) {
   // returns false but should be true because it's less then one day from 4/13/2018 7:30PM
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is the way you are parsing your input. Since `"4/13/2018 7:30:00 PM"` is neither in ISO 8601 nor in RFC 2822 known format, you have to use  [`moment(String, String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) instead of [`moment(String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/):

> When creating a moment from a string, we first check if the string matches known ISO 8601formats, we then check if the string matches the RFC 2822 Date time format before dropping to the fall back of new Date(string) if a known format is not found.
>
> For consistent results parsing anything other than ISO 8601 strings, you should use String + Format.

In your case, you can use:

```
moment("4/13/2018 7:30:00 PM", "M/D/YYYY h:mm:ss A")
```

Instead of

```
moment("4/13/2018 7:30:00 PM")
```